# In a rolling ball (no slipping) do all points move at the same velocity?

Tags: rotation

For example does the centre of the ball rotate at the same speed as a point on the surface of the ball?

Comment: What would the center of the ball *rotate* about at all?

Comment: so the centre wouldnt rotate?

Answer (score 2):

No, every point on a non-slipping ball moves at its own speed.

For every point, the motion is made up of rotation and translation.

If the center of the ball with radius $R$ moves at velocity $v$, then the motion of a point at a distance $r$ can be thought of as the superposition of

- rotation with angular velocity $\omega = \frac{v}{R}$
- translation with velocity $v$

Adding these together, a point will move vertically with a sinusoidal motion with amplitude $r$ and frequency $\omega$ so the velocity will be $$v_v = \omega r \cos(\omega t)$$

the horizontal velocity will be $$v_h = v + \omega r \sin(\omega t)$$

This means that the point that is touching the surface is not moving (at that very instant), while the point at the top is moving at twice the speed of the point at the center. All other points are moving at their own velocity.

Comment: makes sense now